# Where can I look for announcements of tenure-track positions?

Tags: job-search, tenure-track, engineering

I am looking around to land on a tenure track position in the area of systems and control (engineering) and I would be grateful if anyone can suggest a good strategy to identify possible opportunities. I keep seeing people around me getting interviews for positions I have never heard of, so I guess my search strategy needs some improvements.

My main target is the US, but I am open to positions in UK or Canada as well.

Comment: Field? Country?

Comment: @astronat You are perfectly right, I edited my question including the information you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: @Thomas I tried on Indeed but I did not find anything interesting. Also, I signed up for a monthly mailing list in my field, but I believe many positons are not advertised there.

On a related note, another thing I did not say is that I am actually trying to move out from an assistant professor position in France. I am not very happy here.

Comment: The people writing your recommendation letters should know where to look for job ads. Have you asked them? If none of them are familiar with the system you are applying to, then I think that presents a bigger problem that you should solve first.

Comment: @Thomas I see. I will ask them, but I would like to start my research independently.

Comment: Most fields have a few central job posting sites. For me, https://cra.org/ads/ was a one-stop shop. Hopefully you can find a good job site just by googling. E.g. searching for "assistant professor computer science jobs" turns up several links worth exploring.

Comment: @frank You should indeed "start your research independently", but that does not mean that you should not rely on strategic advice from your mentors. It's a common mistake to think that "being independent" means that you should now figure everything out yourself. It does not.

Comment: Most positions in Canada will require you to be a professional engineer (licensed by the provincial board of P. eng.), which is a pain to get as a foreigner (and takes years, depending on the province).

Comment: There might be special communities around the internet for ur field. try Google groups for instance. Also, search highered jobs https://www.higheredjobs.com/ , I also recommend u to look at researchgate jobs at: https://www.researchgate.net/jobs , Hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google Search of

> X faculty position ads

turns up a rather lengthy list of position ads, but they also include the websites which those ads are posted on. You can then "fan out" from there. (It defaults to jobs within 200 miles of your location, so you'll want to change that setting to "any" to see all the jobs it can find.)

Additionally, the professional society for your discipline or another similar organization probably has some sort of "clearinghouse" site where such announcements are collected. For example, in my discipline (Chemical Engineering), an organization called CACHE offers a central posting site for such positions. In other countries, there may be regulations requiring the positions be advertised in specific locations as well.

And, of course, it's possible to ask your friends, mentors, and colleagues where to look for positions! Independence doesn't mean you have to go it completely alone!